# Mercurial hook precommit get repository path

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I'm coding a script to check syntax of repository files.

So, I added to my **.hgrc** file this line :

```
precommit = python ~/tools/check_syntax.py
```

But I want get the path of repository in which I try to commit from **check_syntax.py** file.

Do you know a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg root` will give you the top of your current working directory. So something like:

```
[hooks]
precommit = python ~/tools/check_syntax.py $($HG root)
```

will set the top of your current working directory as first argument of your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works ! I don't found anything mention it in documentation.